how to switch azure container app workload profile from consuption to dedicated workload profile?
I have created an azure container app with quick image. Here my container app is in consumption workload profile as when deploying with quick start image there is no option to select between workload profiles.
Now I want to switch my container app's workload profile from consumption to the dedicated workload profile which I have created.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this?
Thank You..
I couldn't find a legit solution for this.
I am able to add dedicated workload profiles in the container apps Environment. So I have just Deleted my container app and created again but this time with an explicit docker image. Here it gave me choice to select between my workload profiles.

You can change on Azure Portal, Container App Overview page, Properties, Workload profile.

Unfortunately there is no way to switch profile from an already running container app. To switch your Azure Container App's workload profile from Consumption to Dedicated, you will need to redeploy your app with the dedicated profile.
By the way, when creating a container app with a quick start image, you are limited to the Consumption workload profile only. However, when deploying with an explicit Docker image, you will be given the option to select from your available workload profiles.

Delete your current container app.

Create and push your explicit Docker image to your acr


Select the dedicated workload profile you want to use during the creation process.


az containerapp env workload-profile add \
  --name ArkoContainerAppEnv \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --workload-profile-name ArkoDedicate \
  --workload-profile-type D4 \
  --min-nodes 1 \
  --max-nodes 2



Create a new container app with an explicit Docker image with the workload profile

az containerapp create \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name arkocontainerapp1 \
  --image arkoacr1.azurecr.io/sample-app:v1 \
  --environment ArkoContainerAppEnv \
  --workload-profile-name ArkoDedicated \
  --cpu 1 \
  --memory 2Gi


You can verify or edit the same from by using
az containerapp show --resource-group arkorg--name arkocontainerapp1 > current-config.json


if you do any edit in the workloadprofile then you can update it using-
az containerapp update --resource-group arkorg--name arkocontainerapp1 --set workloadProfileName=vivekdedicated


@VivekPanchal is your issue resolved?
